# How do I get the highest value from value in PHP multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, max, grouping, composite-primary-key

I have data in php

```
$data = [
  ["tahun" => 2001, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 0],
  ["tahun" => 2002, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 0],
  ["tahun" => 2002, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 1],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 0],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 1],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 2],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 3],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 4],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 2, "pembetulan" => 0]
];
```

How do I get the highest `pembetulan` data for each `tahun` and `bulan`?

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate a result array which is temporarily assigned associative first-level keys based on the two columns that uniquely identify the desired grouping.

As you iterate, if the identifying key does not exist in the result array or if the retained `pembetulan` is less than the currently iterated row's `pembetulan` value, then save the current row in the result.

When finished iterating, remove the temporary first-level keys with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ISp0A))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $compositeKey = $row['tahun'] . '_' . $row['bulan'];
    if (!isset($result[$compositeKey]) || $row['pembetulan'] > $result[$compositeKey]['pembetulan']) {
        $result[$compositeKey] = $row;
    }
}
var_export(
    array_values($result)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'tahun' => 2001,
    'bulan' => 1,
    'pembetulan' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'tahun' => 2002,
    'bulan' => 1,
    'pembetulan' => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'tahun' => 2003,
    'bulan' => 1,
    'pembetulan' => 4,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'tahun' => 2003,
    'bulan' => 2,
    'pembetulan' => 0,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

$data = [
  ["tahun" => 2001, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 0],
  ["tahun" => 2002, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 0],
  ["tahun" => 2002, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 1],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 0],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 1],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 2],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 3],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 1, "pembetulan" => 4],
  ["tahun" => 2003, "bulan" => 2, "pembetulan" => 0]
];

$tahun = array();
$bulan = array();
$pembetulan = array();
foreach($data as $group){
    if(!in_array($group['tahun'], $tahun)){
        $tahun[] = $group['tahun'];
    }
    if(!in_array($group['bulan'], $bulan)){
        $bulan[] = $group['bulan'];
    }
}
$maxValue_t = 0;
$maxValue_b = 0;
foreach($data as $value){
    foreach($tahun as $t){
        if($value['tahun'] == $t){
            if($maxValue_t < $value['pembetulan']){
                $maxValue_t = $value['pembetulan'];
            }
            $pembetulan['tahun'][$t] = $maxValue_t; 
        }
    }foreach($bulan as $b){
        if($value['bulan'] == $b){
            if($maxValue_b < $value['pembetulan']){
                $maxValue_b = $value['pembetulan'];
            }
            $pembetulan['bulan'][$b] = $maxValue_b; 
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($pembetulan);die;
//Output
Array
(
    [tahun] => Array
        (
            [2001] => 0
            [2002] => 1
            [2003] => 4
        )

    [bulan] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
        )

)
```

Please check if this is helpful for you.

Comment: Please read my answer Vishal.  This task is much easier than you are making it.

Comment: I think this code is still not correct because there is one missing in 2003 month 2 no results, but thanks to this code I can develop it